# Can you play Big Two with multiple decks for more than 4 players?

Tags: big-two

We have 5-7 players, which is too much for one normal game and not enough for two. We could just deal less cards per player, but it would reduce the strategy involved. Are there any variants for using multiple decks?

Alternatively, are there any obvious problems with just dealing out 65-91 cards from two combined decks? We're  not concerned with the increased game length due to having more players. I'd imagine cards playing the same value would tie and therefore wouldn't be allowed after each other (i.e. you can't play a 5 of clubs on a 5 of clubs). This might also open up new poker hands (e.g. 5 of a kind)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can play big 2 with more than one deck.  I would recommend two decks for 6-8 players, three decks with 9+.  (5 player is tougher, two decks is too many, one is maybe not enough, but I would err on the side on playing one deck for five players, unless you want a particularly wild game).

Higher level hands such as 5 of a kind should be allowed.

Regarding tied cards, there are several different rules variants of how to play the game.  Some allow it, some disallow it, and some play that playing a duplicate card causes the next player in line to be 'skipped' and lose their opportunity to play.  Experiment and figure out which way your group prefers.